# android search with suggestions

Tags: android, search, search-suggestion

I want to make a search with suggestions.

after running the app and typing a string in my search box non of the following Logs `Log.d("states","a onCreate")`, `Log.d("states",arg0.toString())`, `Log.d("states",query)` or `Log.d("states","searchactivity onCreate")` execute.

What do I have to do do so the `query()` method in a.java or the `onCreate()` method in b.java are called?

Please dont send me to google developer documents its very confusing.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.searchapp;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("states","MainActivity onCreate");

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the options menu from XML
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
        //searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);

        return true;
    }

}
```

**a.java**

```
package com.example.searchapp;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class a extends ContentProvider{

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("states","a onCreate");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri arg0, String[] arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3,
            String arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("states",arg0.toString());
        String query = arg0.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase();
        Log.d("states",query);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**b.java**

```
package com.example.searchapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class b extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("states","searchactivity onCreate");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

          Log.d("states",query);

        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.searchapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <provider 
            android:name=".a"
            android:authorities="com.example.searchapp.searchsuggestion">
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".b">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="app_label"
    android:hint="Search in tags"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.searchapp.searchsuggestion"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW" >

</searchable>
```

Comment: no one can help me ?!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your a-class you have to implement the getType()-method:

```
private UriMatcher uriMatcher; 

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
   final String authority = "com.example.searchapp.searchsuggestion";
   uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
   uriMatcher.addURI(authority, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
   uriMatcher.addURI(authority, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);
   return true;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
           return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
     }
}
```

Comment: did you test my code and your solution? your solution didnt work for me :(